# Functions within VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to read the output from multiple components and display them within an integer form. The outputs are all 4-bit vectors. As I do not want to have to repeat the code numerous times, I am trying the use of functions native to VHDL. I have not used these before and also cannot see much well-explained documentation online.

```
function FourBitsToNumber (X : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0))
return integer is
begin
if (X = "0000") then return 0;
  elsif (X = "0001") then return integer(1);
  elsif (X = "0010") then return integer(2);
  elsif (X = "0011") then return integer(3);
  elsif (X = "0100") then return integer(4);
  elsif (X = "0101") then return integer(5);
  elsif (X = "0110") then return integer(6);
  elsif (X = "0111") then return integer(7);
  elsif (X = "1000") then return integer(8);
  elsif (X = "1001") then return integer(9);
 end if;
end FourBitsToNumber;
```

I am calling the function on the clock pulse with the following code:

```
variable1 <= FourBitsToNumber(A);
```

...With 'variable1' being of type integer declaration. 'A' is a 4-bit vector.

However, from my test bench, I can see that the line of code is being reached but am just receiving a value of 0 throughout (even when I know it should be more).

My guess is maybe the syntax or another stupid error on my behalf.

Comment: why not use the unsigned and to_integer functions? see my answer for below :)

Comment: It's not possible to tell you why your function call always returns 0 without a [mcve]. Note there are several deficiencies in your function. An array of std_ulogic elements can contain more than just binary values '0' and '1'. There's no return value  for those cases nor for binary values > 9. This would result in an error should FourBitsToNumber's parameter be presented with either of those cases. You'd either need an else or could use a case statement with an others choice.

Comment: @dyslexicgruffalo - ***why not use the unsigned and to_integer functions?*** unsigned is a type declared in IEEE package numeric_std in your answer. It's use is in a type conversion with particular syntax and semantics, a basic operation and not a function call. The nuneric_std package is found in reference library IEEE.

Comment: The if statement's conditions in the subprogram body of function FourBitsToNumber don't require parentheses. Condition expressions are syntactically distinct in VHDL and any expression enclosed in parentheses is also valid without parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
function my_int(X : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)) return integer is
    begin
        return to_integer(unsigned(X));
end function my_int;
```

I have a feeling that this could also work with an undefined length slv...
e.g.

```
function my_int_of_any_len(X : std_logic_vector) return integer is
    begin
        return to_integer(unsigned(X));
end function my_int_of_any_len;
```

Matthew's suggestion: (see his comment below)

```
function my_int(X : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)) return integer is
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    begin
        return to_integer(unsigned(X));
end function my_int;
```

I should also point out that you dont actually have to build your own function for this. Where you have said that you want an integer, just put `variable1 <= to_integer(unsigned(X));`

Comment: You can make these functions completely self-contained by inserting the use clause between the `is` and the `begin`, ie `) return integer is use ieee.numeric_std.all; begin` (with some newlines for clarity, obvs). There's a free taster of "Expert VHDL" for you.

Comment: oh thanks, Matthew, yes I completely forgot you can add that in too!